# pass the $scope variable to another function angularjs

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

I am a novice with Angularjs, I am trying to pass a $scope variable to anther javascript function so I can display number 10 onto variableFromHTML using ng-bind but I do not see the number 10 being display at all, can someone shed some light for me?

**script:**

```
var someVariable= angular.module('someModule', []);

    someVariable.controller('someController', function($scope){
        anotherFunction($scope);
    });

    function anotherFunction($scope){
        $scope.variableFromHTML = 10;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<span ng-bind="variableFromHTML"></span>
```

Comment: That's possible, no issues. http://plnkr.co/edit/LhJ3sY9j1gjebUyYDOTb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

can u use ng-model instead? and also debug and see if $scope has scope.variableFromHTML has 10.

Answer (score 0):

[**Works as expected.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lL9RCT8aJH2olEOvo28r?p=preview)

Make sure you have used `ng-controller`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to do is not required. Either you can set the $scope variable directly in the controller like this:

```
var someVariable= angular.module('someModule', []);

someVariable.controller('someController', function($scope){
   $scope.variableFromHTML = 10;
});
```

Or if you want to use a function try to have that function in angular scope so that it is not global and inside the controller. Like this:

```
var someVariable= angular.module('someModule', []);

someVariable.controller('someController', function($scope){
    $scope.anotherFunction = function(){
    $scope.variableFromHTML = 10;
}
});
```

By Default the $scope will be available for this function.

If it is required that you want to share this function (that is why you were making it dynamic) then at that case you can make use of an angular service.